# Consuming assembly registered with GAC

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, assemblies

I successfully installed a .dll I created through visual studio.net, because it says "Assembly successfully added to the cache".  (I used create-file option to generate strongly named type--following a cookbook, but I don't know exactly how all this fits together--then I did `gacutil -i xxxx.dll`, and the dll has a bunch of classes under the `IQBooks.Shapes` namespace).

How do I consume this assembly when I do Project --> Add Reference?

All classes in the project were given to `IQbooks.Shapes` namespace, but I don't see that anywhere in Project --> Add Reference.

I was expecting `IQBooks.Shapes` to show up under the Names column in the Assemblies tab, but I did a search on every tab, and can't find it.

Am I missing a step?  Or do I have the concept completely botched up in my head...?

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I am using c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably on the wrong learning path.  Instead of worrying about the GAC and using VS 2015, use Visual Studio 2017, and use NuGet packages managing dependencies.

To answer your question the you set the .DLL reference to some copy of your DLL.  The GAC comes in at Assembly Load time, providing a single system-wide copy of the library, and giving you a single place to update the library and have that affect all the applications.

It's rare that you would use the GAC in any new development.

Comment: If it is added to GAC why wouldn't you see any clue of it being there?  I understand that you can add reference dll, but if you are going the GAC route, you should be able to piont to copy in GAC....

Comment: Visual Studio simply never implemented a feature where you could add a reference to an assembly directly from the GAC.  Which is, indeed, inconvenient when dealing with third-party assemblies that are installed directly into the GAC.